# Microsoft Office 365: Room resources from external domain

Tags: exchange, outlook, office365

Two Orgs: A and B, both on Office 365 Email.

Org A has list of physical meeting rooms available on-demand for booking and use by whitelisted email@domains

Org B has users who want to:

1. Search and find meeting rooms belonging to Org A using Outlook client
2. Send calendar invites to block rooms

In reality, there will be ~25-50s orgs like Org B wanting to search and block rooms owned Org A.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, if two office 365 mailboxes from different organizations, regardless of the shared calendar is from a user mailbox or resource mailbox, you could only view the meetings and room resources which don't show the real location in the calendar. In the same way, you couldn't find the room resources from a different organization for design reasons.